# Degrafa Creates Error In LayoutManager In Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am Having Project In Flex 3.6 & Now Converting It To 4.6... I Used Degrafa In 3.6 For Some Perpose But Now It Is Creating Error

```
Error: Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.
    at mx.managers.layoutClasses::PriorityQueue/removeSmallest()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\layoutClasses\PriorityQueue.as:238]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:752]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:819]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

In Debug Traces I Reached To This =>

```
override public function get width():Number{........
override public function get height():Number{........
```

These Two Functions Are Being Called Continuously From Backend Causes Hang FlashPlayer From 
< public class RegularRectangle extends Geometry implements IGeometry >

And When I Tried It In Debug Mode At That Time Function Hangs At =>

```
package mx.managers.layoutClasses
```

in -> class PriorityQueue of Flex Framework

```
for (var key:Object in bin.items )
            {
                obj = key;
                removeChild(ILayoutManagerClient(key), maxPriority);
                break;
            }
```

---

Kindly Suggest Me Any Patch Or Any Other Solution For Degrafa Or Which Library Can I Use Instead **Degrafa**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using Degrafa library for some time in a Flex 4.6 project and it's apparently running fine with this version. The only issue I've encountered was with some of the Degrafa's components when upgrading to AIR 3.9 (you can read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484326/flex-degrafas-bezier-spline-under-air-3-9/21495317#21495317) but it was for the bezier-curve component anyway), but nothing wrong before that.

If not done already, you should try **upgrading the library to its latest patch. Their website is down but you can still find latest downloads** [here](http://code.google.com/p/degrafa/downloads/list).

About your question "What library can I use instead?", tell us which components are you interesting in. If you're only using one or two from Degrafa, it could be found somewhere else easily.